# how to open print window after creating pdf in dompdf?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

i converted my html to Pdf using dompdf and i want to print it. My problem is how to open my pdf file in print window instead of opening the download dialog?

```
include('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

$savein = 'pdfdirectory/';  

$html = " my htmlcode here " 

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);            
$dompdf->render();      

$pdf = $dompdf->output();             
file_put_contents(($savein.'file.pdf'), $pdf);           

$dompdf->stream('file.pdf');
```

Comment: Apart from this PHP code do you have any HTML page or code ?

Comment: @Chandresh i have html page which has a table and a print button above of it that directed to this php code when clicked

Answer (score 5):

You can't force the user to open the file in their browser, but you can specify options for the [`stream()`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#stream) method that hint to the browser whether or not to download the file. The default is to tell the browser that the file is an "attachment" which usually translates to a download. But if you modify the last line of your code as follows most browsers should display the PDF in the browser:

```
$dompdf->stream( 'file.pdf' , array( 'Attachment'=>0 ) );
```